# MessageBox VB sale detras

Tags: .net, vb

A la hora de eliminar un objeto, confirmo mediante un `MessageBox`
 (`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`), pero al ser una aplicación web, este `MessageBox` sale detrás del navegador.
el código es el siguiente:

```
  Dim result As Integer = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Traductor.Traducir("pregEliminar"), Traductor.Traducir("ElVehi"), System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

Y de ahí ya paso a la confirmación.

El caso es: ¿Como puedo hacer un "popup" (sin JS) o un `MessageBox` que salga delante del navegador?

Saludos!

Comment: Que tecnología estás utilizando? Web Forms? MVC? Para mostrar un popup si o si necesitas hacerlo con JS. Si utilizas Bootstrap este utiliza modal.js donde viene todo resuelto. Si no podés utilizar JQuery UI.

Comment: Entiendo que es asp.net...si es asi, los mensajes deben ir en javascript.

Comment: @Pikoh ok, era todo lo que necesitaba saber. Muchas gracias!